# Sobolev space and norm

Tags: analysis

Is it true that we have equivalence between these two norms?

$\|u\|_{H^{k}}^{2}\sim \|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}+\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=k} \|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$

Is it also true that we have this inequality and if it is true how can I prove it?

$\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=2k} \|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}\le \|\Delta ^{k}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$
where $\Delta=\sum_{i \le N}\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}$

Here I am working on a bounded smooth domain $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R^{N}}$

Comment: Hello. This looks a lot like questions you may have been asked on an assignment or problem set.

Could you please indicate if that is correct and, either way, what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Simon  actually I try to study partial differential equation this summer just a personal effort and I read the book of Distribution of Claude Zuily so sometimes he doesn't prove every thing  like regularity of solution of heat equation

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, as a function $u \in H^2$ is zero on the boundary, you can integrate by parts to get that for all $i$,
$$
\|\partial_iu\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \int_\Omega \partial_iu \cdot \partial_iu = -\int_\Omega u\partial_i^2u \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|\partial_i^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
$$
Using this on the different derivatives of $u \in H^k$, you can always bound the $L^2$ norm of $D^\alpha u$ in function of the $D^\beta u$ and the $D^\gamma u$ for $|\beta| = |\alpha| - 1$ and $|\gamma| = |\alpha| + 1$ so you bound $\|u\|_{H^k(\Omega)}$ in function of $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^2}$.

Second point is obviously false because the right hand side is the same as the left hand side but with fewer terms so I guess you forgot a mutliplicative constante. When $u$ is smooth with compact support in $\Omega$, use the fact that for all $i,j$,
$$
\|\partial_i\partial_ju\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = \left<\partial_i\partial_ju,\partial_i\partial_ju\right>_{L^2(\Omega)} = \left<\partial_i^2u,\partial_j^2u\right>_{L^2(\Omega)} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\|\partial_i^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{1}{2}\|\partial_j^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)},
$$
because $\partial_i^* = -\partial_i$ for the scalar product in $L^2$. It should help you to get the wanted inequality.

Comment: Thank you @cactus yes I miss a constant in the second one so it must be$\sum_{\lvert \alpha\rvert=2k} \|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}\le C \|\Delta ^{k}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$
 Right?and a second question can I use elliptic regularity to say that $\|u\|_{H^{2}}^{2}\le \|\partial_{t}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$
 Where I is solution of heat equation in bounded regular domain with $u=0$ in boundary of $\Omega$?Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think it is useful to consider the heat equation, but maybe it works, I don't know.